# How to recover the inputs values entered by the user. knowing that the inputs are created dynamically with *ngFor directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to retrieve the input data from the td of my array in my typescript .ts file. Knowing that these  cells are dynamically generated using the ngFor directive. I only get the input written in hard. but not the other input generated dinamically. I would like to retrieve input value entered by user.

**here is my html file :**

```
<tbody id="tbody">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="test"></td>
                    <td *ngFor="let column of table.columns"><input type="{{ column.type }}" name="cell" maxLength="{{ column.length }}" required="{{ column.nullable }}" value="{{ column.dataDefault }}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="test"></td>
                    <td *ngFor="let column of table.columns"><input type="{{ column.type }}" name="cell" maxLength="{{ column.length }}" required="{{ column.nullable }}" value="{{ column.dataDefault }}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="test"></td>
                    <td *ngFor="let column of table.columns"><input type="{{ column.type }}" name="cell" maxLength="{{ column.length }}" required="{{ column.nullable }}" value="{{ column.dataDefault }}"></td>
                </tr>
```

**Here is my component.ts file**

```
getDataTable() {
const names = this.table.columns.map(col => col.name);
console.log(names.length);

const inputValue = document.querySelector('#tbody').querySelectorAll('input');
console.log(inputValue);

const blob = new Blob(['INSERT INTO TYPPAR(' + names + ')'], {type: 'text/plain'});
console.log(blob);
```

}

**here is my result :**

[image]

I only retrieve input with test value and I want to get data input for input generated with ngFor

Comment: two-way databinding or ngModel